# jQuery filter example: cascading filters

Tags: jquery

How can I cascade several filters in jQuery? Following example is not working:

```
$(":input[type='submit' name='next']");
```

Comment: you can use `$("input[type='submit']").filter("[name='next']")`

Comment: @TusharGupta, i think filter will look for `children` elements which has `name=next`. Here he expect both attribute in same element

Comment: @Murali check --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PQt4u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  [`Multiple attribute`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) selector

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='next']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit' and name='next']");
```

this should work